# Access 2007 Filter a Calculated IF Statement Field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a query that has a this calculated field:

```
MonthEligible: IIf([5yrAnniv]>=DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())+1,1),[5yrAnniv],IIf([5yrAnniv]<=DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())+1,1),DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())+1,1),""))
```

And then I have another field that's also calculate based on this:

```
Eligible?: IIf(DatePart("m",[MonthEligible])=(DatePart("m",Date())+1),"YES","NO")
```

Basically, the first one calculates the month in which they are eligible, and the second one says "YES" if that month is next month, or "NO" if it isn't.

From there, I want to filter the second field to just show the YES records.  But when I put "YES" in the criteria and click View, Access prompts me to put in a value for `[MonthEligible]`.  How do I get it to not do this?  I want it to use the existing `[MonthEligible]` field that works when there's no criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You logic makes little sense. What you probably are after, could be something like this:

```
MonthEligible: IIf([5yrAnniv]>DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())+1,1),[5yrAnniv],DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())+1,1))

Eligible: IIf(DateDiff("m",Date(),[5yrAnniv])>1,"YES","NO")
```

Comment: Your logic for MonthEligible works but your Eligible logic doesn't work for what I need.  Don't worry about it though, as my problem is the filtering.